# Bot Framework publish and deploy to Azure from VS 2019 - missing files

Tags: azure, deployment, botframework

I wrote a C# web bot using external resources (.lg and .dialog files), which - as I think - are not deployed along with the code. I deploy from VS2019, right click and "publish / azure / Azure App Service (windows 10)" into an already existing app service.

Which are the worst that asks almost nothing, I cant see how I can add files to the publishment package. The bot wont work on azure portal, after several hours I found where are the log files, and see that it says cant open the .lg file because it is missing.

In the adaptive dialog constructor:

```
this.Generator = new TemplateEngineLanguageGenerator(Templates.ParseFile(Configuration["Dialog.Templates.Root"]));
```

in my appsettings.json:

```
"Dialog.Templates.Root": "Templates/root-dialog-templates.lg",
```

How can I add files to copy along during the deployment?

Thanks for any suggestion and help!

Comment: You can use embedded resources for them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

Comment: Ohh thank you reminding me not to reinvent the wheel ... again. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include something like this sample in your `.csproj` file, assuming your `.lg`, `.dialog` files are under the `Dialogs` folder

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Dialogs\**\*.lg" />
    <None Remove="Dialogs\**\*.dialog" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Dialogs\**\*.lg">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Dialogs\**\*.dialog">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This way you'll find the deployed files in the same folder relative to the project's content root, which is usually current directory.

Comment: Found the same solution right now: the setting 'copy always' will automatically add the file during the publishing process.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help 